# Why does open('uri').read delete the response data?

Tags: ruby

If I open a URI and read a the response as follows:

```
response = open("https://www.example.com")
result = response.read
```

That works fine, but if I then call response.read again an empty string is returned. This seems like odd behavior. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because OpenURI is returning a [`Tempfile`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) object, which is a special implementation of the `File` class:

> A Tempfile objects behaves just like a File object, and you can perform all the usual file operations on it: reading data, writing data, changing its permissions, etc. So although this class does not explicitly document all instance methods supported by File, you can in fact call any File instance method on a Tempfile object.

And a `File` class' parent is an `IO` object. Which means when you call `read` you're calling an [`IO` implementation of the method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-read).

What all of this means is that you're reading a file when doing `response.read` and you're reading until end of file. Which is why you're getting an empty string when you do a second read, because you're trying to read from the end of file, which has nothing.

Here's one way to examine this and see what's going on:

```
require 'open-uri'
response = open('http://google.com')
puts response.class # => Tempfile

puts response.read  # => <!doctype html><html ...
puts response.pos   # => 10941

puts response.read  # => ""
response.rewind
puts response.pos   # => 0
puts response.read  # => <!doctype html><html ...
```